# exception 'System.ArgumentException'

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am loading the data from MySQL in DataGridView and trying to to show the data from grid view to the textboxes and picture box. When I am trying to load the image from datagridview to the picture box it throws an exception. I have wasted my 2 days to resolve it but I remain unsuccessful.

This is the exception which I get when I click on the cell:

[image]

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            id.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            cost.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            price.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            status.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            description.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            //picture.Image = (Image)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value; 

            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value != DBNull.Value)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);

                picture.Image = Image.FromStream(ms); // here is exception
            }
            else
            {

                picture.Image = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think in order for that to work, your `MemoryStream` has to be an actual image.  In other words, the data needs to be in some image format, and apparently it's not.

Comment: If you're sure you're actually clicking on an image, you should attempt to retrieve that image from the event handler's arguments, not from the grid directly.

Comment: What is `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value`? And how did you put it in there in the first place? Instead of reading in from the grid, try going to the source of where you're getting that data from in the first place (query to a database, etc). As mentioned above, it should be a binary array, or something similar (a binary representation of an image); it's unlikely you have this type of info in your grid.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i am not clicking on the image i am clicking on a row so the data fo whole row is shifted in textboxes and picture box

Comment: Can you obtain the whole row from the event arguments?

Comment: @Jonathan dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value is a value of fifth column(image) of the specific row on which the click event is set. i am trying to show the data to user in grid and hen user click on a specific row the data should be shifted above on textboxes or picture boxes so user can updated the data and picture

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes i am obtaining the whole row

Comment: Alright.  Now find the cell of interest in that row.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the image is throwing the exception when it tries to load in picture box

Comment: Yes, I get it.  Do you understand that I want you to get the image from the row in the event arguments, and not from the grid, directly?

Comment: @yousef Please re-read my question. I'm not asking what you want to have in that cell, I am asking what is the `.Value` of the cell, as well as other specifics. I know that cell[5] is the 5th column -- well actually, it's likely column 6 as cells are zero-indexed

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews

Comment: @RobertHarvey the DataGridViewCellEventArgs class does not contain the row, it only contains the columnIndex and RowIndex. I believe he is getting the data from the cell he wants in the correct fashion. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @RobertHarvey no

Comment: @Window: OK.  What about `object Sender`?  It's gotta be in there somewhere.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I believe you are right. I believe that it's possible to cast the `sender` to `DataGridView` and then access the `CurrentRow` property; however, I'm not 100% if that's the correct row. It's been a while since I last used a DataGridView

Comment: @mjwills ?dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.GetType() it giving this {Name = "Byte[]" FullName = "System.Byte[]"}

Answer (score 0):

If binary representation of the image is malformed, you'll get this error:

```
var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(@"Qk16AAAAAAAAAHYAAAAoAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAQAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAgAAAAICAAIAAAACAAIAAgIAAAICAgADAwMAAAAD/AAD/AAAA//8A/wAAAP8A/wD//wAA////APAAAAA=");
var img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageBytes)); // ok


var badImageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(@"Qk16AAAAAAAAAHYAAAAoAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAQAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAgAAAAICAAIAAAACAAIAAgIAAAICAgADAwMAAAAD/AAD/AAAA//8A/wAAAP8A/wD//wAA////APAAAA==");
var badImg = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(badImageBytes )); // not ok
```

The simplest way to check consistency of the value will be to save it to the file and try open with any image viewer.

```
var bytes = (byte[])dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value;
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\image.base64.txt", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)); // if image is not confidential you may share it with the community in the comment
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\image.bmp", bytes);
```

Please note that only [following image formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Image_FromFile_System_String_) are supported:

- BMP
- GIF
- JPEG
- PNG
- TIFF

The reason why it is malformed could be different:

- someone uploaded non-valid image
- there are some data transformation (compression/encryption)
- data was truncated in the storage (check DDL of the column if it is SQL)